# char text[] = R"() C++ как добавить переменную

Tags: c++, строки, char

есть кусок кода

```
char text[] = R"(
{
    "chtoto": {
        "Blabla":30,
    }
}
    )";
```

Тут Массив text хранит данные для последующей записи в .json файл как реализовать ввод переменных(к примеру в место 30 поставить переменную в которую будет приходить значение) или же другой способ, чтоб можно было сделать вывод в .json файл

Comment: Возьмите нормальную библиотеку для работы с JSON. Например https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char text[120];
int N = 40;
sprintf(text,R"(
{
    "chtoto": {
        "Blabla":%d,
    }
}
    )", N);
```

Устроит такое?

Но лучше все же со строками работать, там проще — не надо думать о размере буфера, например. А если версия компилятора позволяет, то использовать форматирование строк.

Comment: можете пояснить как это работает просто я не совсем понимаю.. и как сделать если у нас допустим не 1 переменная а больше?

Comment: просто в программе должна быть система сохранения конфигов(в 1 json файле) и они будут примерно так записаны

Comment: См. описание функции [`sprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). Хоть 10, хоть 20, хоть...

Answer (score 2):

В C++ используются потоки для формирования строк

```
int main() {
    int num_data;
    std::cin >> num_data;
    std::ostringstream text_stream;
    text_stream << R"({
    "chtoto": {
        "Blabla":)"
<< num_data
<< R"(,
    }
})";
    std::cout << text_stream.str();
    return 0;
}
```

[Ссылка на код](https://onlinegdb.com/90rfn69Bc)

Comment: проблема в том что у нас должна быть денамическая запись тоесть программа может добавлять ещёзначения

Comment: Тогда нужно использовать специальную библиотеку, например https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Comment: я и пытался только непонимаю как сделать ввод и в инете найти немогу